# Why do I get link errors cross-compiling with MingW32 and not under Linux

Tags: cmake

I have a shared library defined using cmake. Part of the library calls a function that is required to be implemented by the user of the library.

When I compile it on Linux, all works fine. When I cross-compile it using MingW under Cygwin I get link errors on those functions described above, and also any functions in dependent libraries.

My CMakeLists.txt specifies the "add_library" and "target_include_directories" keywords for the library, e.g.:

```
add_library(my_library SHARED my_lib_1.c my_lib_2.c)
target_include_directories(my_library PUBLIC /usr/local/include PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
```

Why does it compile ok on Linux and not Cygwin/MingW?

How can I get it to compile under Cygwin/MingW?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://edll.sourceforge.net/ says:

> As many people may know, DLLs have one limitation: they cannot have
>   even one undefined symbol. This means at the time you create a DLL,
>   you must link it against other DLLs in order to get all the undefined
>   symbols from the object files resolved in some way.
>
> ...
>
> ...With a DLL this doesn't work too well since it can't have undefined symbols and
>   by default a DLL doesn't link back to your application (EXE).

Or to put it another way, "Windows is inadequate, poorly designed, and generally rubbish, and thus completely unable to do half the things that *nixes do without any apparent effort at all".

To answer my own questions above:

1) The shared library compile works on Linux because Linux is tolerant of undefined symbols. If Linux/GCC doesn't need a symbol at the time of linking (because it is creating a shared library) or isn't actually linking (you need to link to create a DLL apparently, but not to created a shared library) then it doesn't demand one. Because Windows has a bad design and architecture, it needs to link all symbols when creating a DLL rather than satisfying all symbols at final link time (i.e. when linking the executable) and thus the shared library compile fails.

2a) A solution is to detect a MingW compile in cmake, and generate an import library for the shared library user and link the shared library to that, as well as all other dependencies. The disadvantage is that this is going to require quite a lot of documentation if I want to distribute the library as a standalone entity.

2b) A second solution is to re-architect my shared library to work around this problem. Personally I am loathe to wreck my existing neat and slim-line design to work around the inadequacies of an operating system I loathe as much for its fascist profiteering as for its general incompetence.